# Javascript - classList.toggle ("my-class") doesn't work because the main class is acquiring more than one

Tags: javascript, html, css

Some Stackoverflow users have suggested using classList.toggle instead of the if and else conditions. So I'm trying to get it to work in my dropdown menu, but I don't understand why it's not working.

clicking the menu items in a completely random way, I find myself with `div class="drop_container hide show"`, so the classes are not alternating as happens with the if and else conditions, but drop_container class is acquiring both hide and show. Is there something wrong ?

**Edit**: Thanks to the comments of all users I realized where I was wrong. The answers I have been given are all correct but none have been the solution for me. The one closest to my problem is the answer given by user @jeremy-denis

**This is the solution I found**: Originally I thought two classes were needed to animate the dropdown closing, in the end I realized that only one class is enough. So I added `transition: max-height 0.3s ease;` to the drop_container class.

This way I no longer have the initial problem with classList.toggle.

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');
//Add this for toggling dropdown
lastOpened = null;

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var menuContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  menuContent.classList.toggle("show");
  
  //Add this for toggling dropdown
  if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== menuContent)
      lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
      lastOpened = menuContent;
}));
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}

.drop_container > .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

<div class="menu-btn">One</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

<div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
<div class="drop_container">
  <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to initialize the elements with either `hide` or `show` in the HTML.

Comment: The logic isn't the same. In the `if` version you're just checking for one class and then flipping both classes.

Comment: Why are you even using two classes for the same thing? Use only one of them, then write CSS for `.hide` and for `:not(.hide)`.

Comment: @Bergi I was also using hide because I wanted to animate the dropdown closing. Without hide, I don't know how. See the second snipet how the closing of the dropdown is animated.

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying but I can't. I'm definitely doing something wrong. Could you answer me with an example if you like? Thanks.

Comment: I misread it when I wrote the first comment. I don't think you can use `toggle()` for this if you need two classes.

Comment: @Snorlax Same thing applies when the CSS does transitions: you need only one class that you add and remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to toggle the class show to be able to hide and show different element

```
  menuContent.classList.toggle("show");
```

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');
//Add this for toggling dropdown
lastOpened = null;

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var menuContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  menuContent.classList.toggle("show");

  //Add this for toggling dropdown
  if (lastOpened && lastOpened !== menuContent)
    lastOpened.classList.remove("show");
  lastOpened = menuContent;
}));
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}

.drop_container.show {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
}

.drop_container.hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
}

.drop_container>.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

  <div class="menu-btn">One</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I also added the hide class because I need to animate the dropdown closing. On the other hand, if show class is removed, it looks like I can't animate the close.

Comment: Add `transition: max-height 0.3s ease;` to the `.drop_container` and you're set

Comment: I have only now read your comment, I have come to the same solution. I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I change your code a little bit.

```js
var dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');
const drop_container = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_container');
//Add this for toggling dropdown
lastOpened = null;

dropdownBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {      
  var menuContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  drop_container.forEach(b => b.classList.remove("show"));
  menuContent.classList.toggle("show");  
 
}));
```

```css
.menu-btn {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-btn:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.drop_container {
  max-height: 0; 
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;  
}

.drop_container.hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
}

.drop_container > .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">

  <div class="menu-btn">One</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-btn">Two</div>
  <div class="drop_container">
    <a class="item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="item" href="#">Visit Us</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. However that is not what I am looking for. I need to close the item both when I click on it and when I switch from one item to another. Also I need a hide class to animate the dropdown closing.